# Including Multiple Classes/ .o files with MinGW Tool in C++

Tags: c++, class, oop, mingw

I want to compile 2 classes into .o file and include them in Test.exe file created from avl.cpp main file.

I use the MinGW tool while doing this, but Nothing happens when I type the command `mingw32-make` into CMD. When I did this with only 1 class, there was no problem.
The content of the makefile file is as follows:

```
all: compile execute

compile:
    g++ -I ./include/ -o ./lib/AVLClass.o -c ./src/AVLClass.cpp
    g++ -I ./include/ -o ./lib/PersonsClass.o -c ./src/PersonsClass.cpp
    g++ -I ./include/ -o ./bin/Test ./lib/PersonsClass.o  ./lib/AVLClass.o ./src/avl.cpp
    
execute:
    ./bin/Test
```

Comment: What is the output of `mingw32-make` exactly?
Also, make sure the indents in `Makefile` are tabs and not spaces.
Finally not that `-I ./include/` has no use in the link step, so you can leave it out in the 3rd g++ line.

Comment: dear @BrechtSanders ;  In this case, although the `mingw32-make` command does not give any output, CMD continues to process and the input screen does not appear at all. Also, when you say, I get `./src/avl.cpp:6:19: fatal error: AVL.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "AVL.hpp"` error when removing `-I ./include/` statement.

Comment: only remove `-I` from the link line (the one combining `.o` files into a `.exe`), not the compile line (= the ones with the `-c` flag).
What do you mean with "input screen does not appear"? Are you you not running this from a shell or command prompt?

Comment: I recorded what I wanted to tell in this screen to [this video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GU8RtfE0wVU7C4Yy-ZFYcwL3THBLeVDg/view?usp=sharing) .

Comment: I overlooked that there was a `.cpp` file on that 3rd line.
You should have a line with `g++ -I ./include/ -o ./lib/avl.o -c ./src/avl.cpp` and then link with `g++ -o ./bin/Test ./lib/PersonsClass.o  ./lib/AVLClass.o ./src/avl.o`.
You say nothing happens when running the `Test.exe`, but it runs without error, it just doesn't return right away.
Is your code somehow waiting for input?
To really figure out what happens you should debug it.
If you don't know how to debug, on http://winlibs.com/ you can find instructions on how to configure CodeBlocks with winlibs' build of GCC and MinGW-w64.

Comment: Normally, it should go to the `execute` step automatically after the `compile` step, but currently it does not go to that step automatically. But manually running the command `./bin/Test`, it runs the created `.exe` file. As you said, the program is normally ok but does not proceed to the next step. Maybe I should debug the way you say. I am grateful for your help.

Comment: You should change the line `execute:` to `execute: compile` to make the execute step depend on the compile step.

Comment: you're welcome. Don't forget to upvote answers and comments that helped you.

Comment: There is no upvote button next to your answers. I'm a new member and this is my first question answered. Is it because of that?

Comment: I will rephrase it as an answer.

Comment: I've upvote your answer and marked it as a solution. I got the following warning: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. My reputation is 11. When my reputation score is 15, I will return here and mark your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makefile uses dependancies to determine what gets built in which order.
So the line `execute:` should really be `execute: compile` to tell make to do the `execute` step after the `compile` step completed.

But you should really split compilation an linking into steps to use the dependancy resolving qualities of make.

Here's how I would do it:

```
BINEXT=.exe
CXX=g++
MKDIR=mkdir -p
RM=rm -f

all: bin/Test$(BINEXT) test

lib/%.o: src/%.cpp
    $(MKDIR) lib
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $^

bin/Test$(BINEXT): lib/AVLClass.o lib/PersonsClass.o lib/avl.o
    $(MKDIR) bin
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^

test: bin/Test$(BINEXT)
    bin/Test$(BINEXT)

clean:
    $(RM) lib/*.o bin/Test$(BINEXT)
```

Note that the indents must be tabs, not spaces.

Actually I wouldn't add `test` to the `all` target. It's better to leave it up to the user if they want to run `make test`.